# Instructing RMarkdown to use relative filepaths or stop shortening folder names

Tags: r, shiny, latex, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a parameterized RMarkdown PDF report that I am running from a Shiny dashboard (after copying it to a temporary directory).

Example code:

Shiny dashboard:

````r
    ---
    title: "Company Report Frontend"
    output: 
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
    ---
    
    ```{r global, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(shiny)
    ```
    
    ### Select Company
    
    ```{r}
    textInput('name', label ='Firm')
    ```
    
    ### Report
    
    ```{r}
    uiOutput("downloadUI")
    
    # Create the actual downloadButton
    output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
        downloadButton("downBtn", "Download Report")
    })
    
    # Add download handling
    output$downBtn <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "full_report.pdf",
        content = function(file) {
            tempReport <- file.path(tempdir())
            file.copy("test_report.Rmd", paste0(tempReport, "/test_report.Rmd"), overwrite = TRUE)
    
            rmarkdown::render(paste0(tempReport, "/test_report.Rmd"), output_file = file,
            params = list(input=input),
            envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()), clean = FALSE,
            knit_root_dir = tempReport,
            )
        }
    )
    ```
````

`test_report.RMD`:

````r
    ---
    title: "Report"
    header-includes: 
       \usepackage{graphicx}
    params:
      input: NA
    output:
      pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
    ---


    ```{r}
    input <- params$input 

    data(mtcars)
    plot(mtcars$hp, mtcars$mpg)
    title(input$name)
    ```
````

When I run it, it successfully produces the `.tex` file but then can't compile it. When I try to compile the `.tex` file directly in a LaTeX editor, I get `undefined control sequence` and `Missing endcsname defined` errors on any `\includegraphics` lines like this one:

```tex
\includegraphics{C:/User/LONGUS~1/Temp/file5b381fa967c8_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf}
```

where `LONGUS~1` is a shortened folder name from the actual Windows username LONGUSERNAME.

The error goes away, and the PDF compiles, if I replace `LONGUS~1` with `LONGUSERNAME`, or just point it to the relative filepath. LaTeX does tend to get finicky about filepaths sometimes.

How can I instruct RMarkdown to either avoid shortening folder names, or skip the absolute filepath and just use the relative? `test_report.RMD` compiles fine if I run it by itself (and specify a default `input`), so I'd guess this is something to do with the use of `tempdir()` or at least something in the `render()` function. But I really should keep the `tempdir()` stuff in the case of multiple simultaneous users of the shiny app. I did try removing the `knit_root_dir` option but that didn't fix it.

Any suggestions welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any problematic characters in your local absolute filepath, such as spaces underscores etc? if yes, try with another path without such characters.

Comment: It doesn't seem to mind the underscore in the relative part of the filepath. There's a ~ in the absolute so maybe that's it, but regardless I'm not going to have control over the filesystem on someone else's computer when they run it, so changing my own local filepath would only delay the issue.

Comment: Can you nevertheless try without special characters to see of this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yep, fair, sorry. It does work in a directory without special characters.

Comment: OK, can you now try with the `grffile` package? if this does not help, please narrow down which character causes the problem

Comment: Does rmarkdown maybe butcher the conversion and replaces ~ with `\space` or something equally silly?

Comment: The special character turns out to maybe be a red herring. Testing `grffile` led me down some more fiddling which has revealed that it appears to be a problem with the way that both tempdir() and render() shorten the folder name. i.e. instead of `longuserfolder-name` it's `LONGUS~1`. If I put it back `longuserfolder-name` it compiles fine, even with the dash.  (my initial no-special-character folder test had too short of a name to show this)

Comment: mabye the here package is usable https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/index.html

Comment: The here package is good thinking but unfortunately doesn't fix this.

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine, but, can you leverage `graphicx` to specify the local image path? You might be able to put

`\graphicspath{{./figure-latex/}}`

in the `header-includes` section after `\usepackage{graphicx}`. This ought to tell LaTeX to use a relative path, but I am not sure how that'll interact with RMarkdown constructing the `\includegraphics` statements.

Comment: This looks like a bug but I you build a correct absolute path upstream with `normalizePath(tempdir())` maybe it'll work ?

Comment: I really thought `normalizePath()` was gonna work! But nope, RMarkdown takes it upon itself to shorten the filepath even after the full proper one is created.